# CSS beginner questions

Tags: css

I'm about to start designing my site that I coded in php. It's a rather complex site...

Obviously, I want to make it suitable for all browsers and devices.

Should I code the CSS using fixed pixels for normal computer dimensions and when I'm done with that make another stylesheet for other devices such as iphone and ipad?

Or should I attempt to make an adaptive site that works with all resolutions? In this case, should I look into CSS frameworks? Any recommendations?

Comment: It all depends on your design priorities, not technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, it depends.  If you think your site is going to be accessed by many devices then you probably want to look at responsive design: http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/ and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/ for more details.

The recommended approach is to take a 'mobile first' approach to the styling, so it works well with little markup for mobile devices and then progressively enhance for other devices with larger resolutions.

You may want to use frameworks or hand-code it - that's something of a personal choice.

If you have significantly different needs for different devices, you may want to create entirely different sites for mobile, similar to the current BBC news for instance, although it's worth noting that many sites including BBC are moving to responsive techniques, so this is a trend that is being adopted more and more.

It's also worth considering which browsers your audience will be using.  As you reach back into older IE versions especially you'll need to look at javascript techniques such as the [respond.js library](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to allow media queries to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some tips for designing a web page that works on ALL screen sizes. I'll delve a bit into media queries and other things too.

- On web pages I've done in the past they usually have existing graphics (usually banners/headers, etc.). so I usually design the web site using a **maximum width** for example, if the banner image that already exists is 900px wide I'm going to make the page 900px wide, more specifically the **content wrapper** will be 900px wide and it's contents will sum to **100%**.
- Keep everything in a **global content wrapper**. This is the easiest way to ensure the page size stays 100% consistent.
- The **sum that makes up the wrapper** should always amount to 100%. Fill the wrapper, but it will never go outside of it. You may have numerous columns or divisions, which you can size at any percentage up to a sum of 100. (like, col1 width="33%", col2 width="33%", col3 width="34%" = 100%)
- Try to pick images that work for ALL screen sizes. There is no built-in way to swap to mobile images when working with responsive web design (there are javascript solutions), but pick an image that looks good when scaled down.
- Avoid scaling an image up. This is why i tend to make the max page size the same size as a header image (if there is one). If the page has no images, 100% liquid layouts are very good too.
- If the content wrapper is fixed, turn it into a percentage with a media query :D example below.

I'm going to write up a basic example of a MAX width 900px page with columns that works on any site mobile/desktop.

**default-style.css**

```
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; /* ie8 */
    border: none;
}
.content_wrap
{
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto !important;
}

/* Columns */
#column-wrap
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#column-left
{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
#column-middle
{
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
}
#column-right
{
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
}
```

**default-queries.css**

```
/* Turn it into a liquid layout at our max-width of 900px */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
    .content_wrap
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* most smart phones */
/* This query will turn all 3 columns into 1 column at 540px */
@media screen and (max-width: 540px)
{
    #column-wrap
    {
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
    }
    #column-wrap div
    {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        float:none; clear: both;
    }
    #column-left
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #column-middle
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #column-right
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Now for the html :D

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link href="default-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="default-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="content_wrap">
<div id="column-wrap">
    <div id="column-left">
        <p>HELLO I"M LEFT COLUMN</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column-middle">
        <p>HELLO IM MIDDLE</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column-right">
        <p>RIGHT</p>
    </div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is a most primitive example of a responsive web site. Using the class **content_wrapper** at a **fixed width** of 900px (because the biggest image im using may be 900px). But when the screen is smaller than 900px, we switch from **fixed** to liquid via **media query** switching to a **liquid width will allow our images to scale down, our text to wrap, and a whole bunch of other great things!**

But, there's more to it than that. That's all we need to do if the page only has linear content, but most pages have different columns to make the most of large screen sizes. This is where media queries REALLY come in handy. If you study the columns, their sum takes up 100% of the content_wrap at all times. And they will scale down for a small website, but they will be really really tiny. This is why I make another media query for smaller screens and eliminate the multi-column layout. Simply clearing the floats and making each column have a width of 100%, will allow for a much more efficient mobile layout.

Anyway, really long answer but hopefully my views/opinions on how to properly design a website with CSS/HTML (php, ASP.net, MVC, etc, can all be thrown in there too) will get you started! Design with a wrapper, media queries, no upscaled images, and images that look good scaled down are really good practices IMO ;)

**I like fixed width pages! They are more universal and prevent over-scaled images** Media queries in CSS3 take care of responsiveness ;)

*I usually DON'T do mobile-first designs, but that's just my personal preference. I see no advantage to one way over the other*

*As stated in another answer, for non-CSS3 browsers response.js works very well*

Answer (score 1):

The two aren't mutually distinctive.

The two approaches are generally:

- Multiple stylesheets, media queries decide which one to load.
- Use fluid measurements (percentages) so the site is fluid.

In reality, you often end up using a bit of both.

There are many issues with trying to do this, one particularly being that older IE doesn't support media queries, and renders everything all the time.

Frameworks are good, but you may find them restrictive. There are many around, and they all basically do the same thing, so just google Responsive CSS framework and see what you find.

I'd also recommend looking into SASS at this point - I use it so I can auto generate an IE stylesheet that has the 960px width version with no media queries, whilst generating another sheet with all the queries in.

Answer (score 1):

Already been answered, I see, but I think what I've got to say is relevant...

Most sites do both a desktop site and a mobile site. Desktop sites are almost always fixed width, with a maximum width at about 1000px. This is starting to change, though, you will see more adaptive sites than in the past. Mobile sites need to have an adaptive width, because of all the crazy different resolutions on all the various phone models out there. I recommend that the smallest width the mobile site should work at is about 320px, because most modern phones are at least that width.

As for mobile detection, take a look at [PHP Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/), it's what I use, and it works pretty well. You just throw in

```
<?PHP
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: /path/to/mobile/site');
} else {
    header('Location: /path/to/full/site');
}
?>
```

at the very top of the first page. You should use a seperate splash page that redirects to something like index2.htm so that users can choose to view the desktop site if they want. It saves you a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to set cookies...

Comment: This is a good solution, I still think it's a bit deprecated since CSS3 is supported on every mobile platform I know of (and responsive.js can fix that otherwise). The only drawback is this won't work for everybody since PHP runs server-side and not all servers support PHP. CSS/JS are client-side which I think is a better approach for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making an adaptive or responsive that can maintain its look across multiple device resolutios. With that being said CSS framework will be your option so your html file is not filled with your topic content and style code.